# Ajax Call reduce response time

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to reduce ajax response time of my website, deployed on Hostinger, it takes around 1.30seconds to get the response on live whereas 220ms on my local machine, is there any way to make it faster on live too? even with null data it takes that much time on live.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of a AJAX-response depends on several influences:

- The speed of the remote machine (=host). Most of the time the
  different sites are only virtual hosts which are multiplexed by a
  bigger machine. So, if you share your space with other
  high-traffic-sites, yours will not respond fast. You can ask your
  provider to give you a new spot on another server of his - helped me
  several times.
- The speed of your connection may be slow or the    connection of your
  provider as well. If you have access to another    test-machine for
  routing-measurements you can check if your connection is really slow. If is not then you may ask your provider to re-route the connection is he is able to.
- Does your AJAX-callmake  excessive usage of databases (e.g. mysql)?
  It could be a slow  database-installation (maybe too many users).
  Normally you can move the database-spot yourself of contact the
  provider to move your databases to another virtual machine.

You see - if it runs at your computer fast and at your provider slow then it is most of the time the problem of your provider and you should contact him.

Comment: You're right, I figured it out on my host server, actually I had activated Cloudflare with high security services on Hostinger, which were causing the actual delay, after setting it up to low security, it fell from 1.3sec to 300ms response time. Thanks

Comment: @Aman Cool - glad it worked out. Please consider voting and/or accepting the answer. Thx.